# Identity Filter Linq .Where

Tags: c#, linq

I need to provide a null where clause that has no effect.

Currently I have:

```
f=>{f!=null;}
```

However that doesn't really look right. If I were to Select clients, I use

```
.Select(clients => clients)
```

With my filter I also get a warning about not all code paths returning a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return `true`:

```
foo.Where(f => true)
```

Your lambda expression doesn't work for three reasons:

- You're trying to use `f != null` as a statement, which it isn't.
- You don't have a return value.
- It would reject null values.

The first two can be fixed by removing the braces:

foo.Where(f => f != null)

The last point means it's not really a no-op filter, which is what I *guess* you meant by "identity filter". Whether it's what you really want or not though, I can't say.

Comment: Jon got the props here because no op was the phrase I was looking for, but coming from a maths background, identity sits in my brain. I removed the braces you are right there, but the simple return true is what I was looking for.